# Cannot run a delete query from specified tables, even with using DISTINCTROW

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run a delete query that involves some joins. I researched and saw that DISTINCTROW was able to be used so I tried this code:

```
DELETE DISTINCTROW Table2.*, Table2.[Field1], Table2_1.[Field1],
Table2.Field2
FROM Table2 AS Table2_1
INNER JOIN (Table2
INNER JOIN [Table3]
ON Table2.Field3 = [Table3].Current)
ON (Table2_1.Field3 = [Table3].Future)
AND (Table2_1.Contract_ID = Table2.Contract_ID)
WHERE (((Table2.[Field1])="R") AND ((Table2_1.[Field1])="R") AND
((Table2.Field2)=[Table2_1].[Field2]));
```

but I'm getting the error `cannot delete from specified tables`. It was working before without the join on the contract ID but now I am getting stuck.

Can anyone provide any insight?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot delete specific fields from a table. That would leave a row with holes in it. You must `DELETE * FROM Table WHERE` if you want to specify on what rows you want to delete.

Comment: Your statement isn't even valid. You have `INNER JOIN (Table2 INNER JOIN [Table3]`, which is invalid syntax.

Comment: Without showing us your Table Schema/Sample Data/Expected results your question is not salvageable.